# mvn and the make package error

Tags: hadoop, snappy

OK. Here's the problem and it's driving me crazy!!!
I followed the instruction online, installed hadoop and when running the text it said snappy local library can't be loaded.
It's said I have to install snappy first and then install hadoop-snappy.
I download snappy-1.0.4 from google code and do the following:
cd ../snappy-1.0.4
./configure
make
sudo make install

Then it's the problem when:
mvn package -Dsnappy.prefix=/usr/local

The post online said by default the snappy should be installed in the /usr/local.
But I got the following error and no matter what I change the path, still get erro:

The goal you specified required a project to execute but there's no POM in the directory. Please verify you invoked the maven from the correct directory.

It's the wrong directory of mvn? Or improper of snappy? And it said lack of pom that should be a .xml that in no where I can find..

Please help!

Comment: what happens when you search for pom.xml in that directory? does it exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't exit. But that's really weird since I followed every step... Do you know how to "make it exist"?

Comment: Is there any reason you cant use 1.1.0, I've just recently installed that one and know it's alright.

Comment: I choose hadoop 1.0.4.... But I think it should be similar. So, you followed some instructions and got no problem??

Comment: wait, what is the command that is failing for you?  It looks like you are using the maven command with hadoop options "the -D"

Comment: the command is mvn package -Dsnappy.prefix=/usr/local

Comment: This instruction is followed after I do the "sudo make install" inside the snappy-1.0.4 directory in order to build the hadoop snappy. also I add the M2_HOME and the path variable to my profile.Still there's error said that no POM is found and the maven should be invoked from the correct directory.

Comment: Well there is definitely no pom file in that directory. What directions are you following? they seem to be incorrect

Comment: http://jiangr.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/build-install-and-configure-snappy-support-for-hbase/

Comment: well.. how should I find the pom.xml.... seems no where to be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so looking at that page, you are in the wrong directory.

The directory you should be in for that step is "hadoop-snappy" which you can see has a pom.xml, you can verify by looking at the github, https://github.com/electrum/hadoop-snappy.

So after you follow these steps from the guide you showed me.

```
Download it(hadoop-snappy) from GitHub
Install libtool, make sure ‘libtoolize’ works
Install Maven 3 if necessary
```

Change your directory to hadoop-snappy and run the command you were trying before.