# Installing snappy for hadoop fails

Tags: maven, hadoop, snappy

I'm following the installation instructions for snappy from here https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-snappy/ . However, I'm not able to complete step 3. I did configure, make, sudo make install and snappy lies in the correct dict in /usr/local. So the next step is installing snappy for hadoop. Therefore as describe I call

```
snappy-1.1.2 Tom$ mvn -e package
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.123s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 05 22:12:10 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/82M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/Tom/Downloads/snappy-1.1.2). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/Tom/Downloads/snappy-1.1.2). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

So, aparently there is no POM file available. Also in the source directory of snappy I do not see any POM files:

```
snappy-1.1.2 Tom$ ls
AUTHORS                           config.guess                      install-sh                        snappy-sinksource.cc              snappy-test.h
COPYING                           config.h                          libsnappy.la                      snappy-sinksource.h               snappy.cc
ChangeLog                         config.h.in                       libtool                           snappy-sinksource.lo              snappy.h
INSTALL                           config.log                        ltmain.sh                         snappy-sinksource.o               snappy.lo
Makefile                          config.status                     m4                                snappy-stubs-internal.cc          snappy.o
Makefile.am                       config.sub                        missing                           snappy-stubs-internal.h           snappy_unittest
Makefile.in                       configure                         snappy-c.cc                       snappy-stubs-internal.lo          snappy_unittest-snappy-test.o
NEWS                              configure.ac                      snappy-c.h                        snappy-stubs-internal.o           snappy_unittest-snappy_unittest.o
README                            depcomp                           snappy-c.lo                       snappy-stubs-public.h             snappy_unittest.cc
aclocal.m4                        format_description.txt            snappy-c.o                        snappy-stubs-public.h.in          stamp-h1
autogen.sh                        framing_format.txt                snappy-internal.h                 snappy-test.cc                    testdata
```

I checked that the requirements (maven3, java 6 etc) are fullfilled. So, how do I get this command to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, question has been answered here: [mvn and the make package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323856/mvn-and-the-make-package-error)

In a nutshell: Go to https://github.com/electrum/hadoop-snappy download the zip and run the `mvn package` command inside the directory where the `pom.xml` lies. That's it.